# Выделить в тексте слова, которые начинаются и заканчиваются с заглавной буквы

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Выделить в тексте слова, которые начинаются и заканчиваются с заглавной буквы и содержат только буквы из латинской азбуки. Мне нужен только Pattern. Внизу примеры входных и выходных данных.

Входные данные

```
GoshO blabla NqmaSm1saL KvoStaA             
AZ AK 47 RoBoT noWayouT                    
DrakonI Navsekyde
```

Выходные

```
GoshO KvoStaA

AZ AK RoBoT

DrakonI
```

Comment: А проблема-то в чем?

Comment: Решаю домашнее задание через три лекции. Пока мы это не изучали, а хочу предварительно подготовиться. использую  -->      \b[A-B]*.?[A-B]\b

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html#introduction_regexexamples

Answer (score 5):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b\\p{Upper}\\p{Alpha}*\\p{Upper}\\b");
```

Еще один идентичный вариант:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*[A-Z]\\b");
```